# How to config Spring @EnableOAuth2Sso App with self-signed SSL OAuth2 Server?

Tags: spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

My app works well with normal non-SSL OAuth2 Servers. But I dont know how to config client to work with the SSL equivalents. I always get 401 when oauth2 server redirects back to `http://localhost:8051/app1/login` after success authentication and granting permissions. My App code likes below:

application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8051
  servlet:
    contextPath: /app1

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: sampleclient
      clientSecret: samplepw
      accessTokenUri: https://localhost:8668/sso-server/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://localhost:8668/sso-server/oauth/authorize
      tokenName: oauth_token
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://localhost:8688/api/me
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class App1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/error**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("https://localhost:8668/sso-server/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("client-session", "JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable()
        ;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App1.class, args);
    }

}
```

OAuth2 Servers work as expected and I can call all oauth APIs that clients need with https schema on Postman, so I think we have nothing to do with them and don't post the code here.

Comment: My Client App might be not required using ssl. And I haven't configed My App1 app using ssl yet. And it should work in both 2 cases. OAuth2 Servers includes: 1 Authorization Server (port 8668) and 1 Resouces Server (port 8688) as references in application.yml above.

Comment: Could you add the reponse (302) with headers of your authorization server. For example a screenshot your dev tool in your browser (F12).